# UTM-метки скрипт на php

Tags: php, denwer

Дали тестовое задание стажера без разъяснений сути задания по utm-меткам, а инфы мало в интернете. Т.е. я должна сделать 2 сайта любых на денвере и организовать связь между ними с помощью реферальной ссылки. Все это надо сделать чисто на php и html.
Вот у меня есть сайт с которого перешли на мой сайт. Например сайт test.ru Как мне считать ссылку сайта, с которого перешли ко мне и utm-метки? И как сделать ссылку с исходного сайта с включением utm-меток:

```
http://test.ru?id=<utm_id>$click=<$utm_content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы отловить откуда пришел пользователь можно использовать `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, но он не всегда правильно даст информацию, по хорошему, нужно добавить дополнительный GET параметр `&ref=https://test2.ru`.

Получить `utm` метки можно используя `$_GET['id']`, если есть какой-то особый вид меток типа `utm_*`, то можно по массиву пройтись и по маске собрать параметры.

А когда уже есть эти параметры в памяти, можно использовать их где угодно.

p.s. надеюсь, я правильно понял суть вопроса

Comment: Нет, вы неправильно поняли суть вопроса.